# Jquery obtain value in gridview in column 2 of selected row

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that I would like to be able to select and obtain the value of the cell in column 2 of the selected row.
My gridview is as follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridviewSLds" runat="server" CellPadding="0" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Both" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCreated="gridviewSLds_RowCreated">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
                            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
                            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
                            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-BorderWidth="0">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="item" HeaderText="Metric" SortExpression="item" ReadOnly="false" />
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox onfocusin="select()" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("item") %>'
                                            ID="txtfocus" class="modalpopup" SelectedRowStyle="myselection" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>

                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Control Type">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox onfocusin="select()" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("itemCtrlType") %>'
                                            ID="txtfocus2" class="modalpopup2" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

I am able to obtain the row index with the following code:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.modalpopup').focus(function () {
                var iIndex = $(this).closest("tr").prevAll("tr").length;

                 });
            });
```

How do I use this to obtain the cell value in column 2 and the row given by iIndex?

Comment: use `:eq()`. `$("table tr:eq("+iIndex+")")` for row...

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.modalpopup').focus(function () {
            var idString = this.id.replace("txtfocus", "txtfocus2");
            var rowNumber = this.id.split("_")[3];
            alert($("#" + idString).val() + " - " + rowNumber);
        });
    });
</script>
```

You just have to make sure that the split function is correct. Check the ID of a textbox in the gridview (should look something like this `ContentPlaceHolder1_gridviewSLds_txtfocus_14`)